# Error while compling the android application - Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My app was compiling properly, before i added an google maps activity. Then i get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.






Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.5.1'



    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')

}
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue. tnx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf

Answer (score 2):

After adding the google maps, the method and references count exceed 64K:

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

This is a big problem that every big project encounter such a problem. But the Google gave a solution : [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question

**Instead of**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Use this

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0
```

This will only include play service required for maps only.Your code will import all packages of play services which will cause your app to cross 64K method limits

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle after the buildTypes{ ... }:

```
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in gradle... your app has reached the 64k reference limit. More of it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

also add this

```
android {

    defaultConfig {

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's suggestion: [Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), you can try to replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'`

with what you need:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx2:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-xxx3:9.6.1'`