# Android-Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForAvsDebug'

Tags: java, android

When I try to Run App on android Studio I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForAvsDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

adding `multiDexEnabled true` didn't solve the problem.

These are gradle files:

**Build.gradle(Module:app):**

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jp.leafytree.android-scala'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.mutualmobile.gradle.plugins.dexinfo'
apply from: 'config/quality.gradle'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
android {
    //Trigger the licenseFormat task at least once in any compile phase
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(rootProject.licenseFormat)
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") as Integer ?: 99999
        versionName rootProject.ext.majorVersion + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        applicationId "com.waz.zclient"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        // Need to exclude all armeabi/mips libs
        // as not all of our libs support these architectures
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libspotify_embedded_shared.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libspotify_sdk.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/librs.blur.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/librs.decode.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/librsjni.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/libRSSupport.so'
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.all {
            // All the usual Gradle options.
            testLogging {
                events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
                outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
                showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    }

    if (file("signing.gradle").exists()) {
        apply from: 'signing.gradle'
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize '4g'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles 'proguard-android-optimize-wire.txt', 'proguard-rules.txt'
            minifyEnabled true
            multiDexEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationVmSafeMode: "false",
                                    localyticsGcmSenderId: "\\ 826316279849"]
        }

        debug {
            // To get debugging properly working again - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177480
            testCoverageEnabled = System.getenv("JOB_NAME").equals("full-test-coverage")
            versionNameSuffix = " " + getDate()
            multiDexEnabled true
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationVmSafeMode: "true",
                                    localyticsGcmSenderId: "\\ 826316279849"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationId "com.waz.zclient.dev"
            versionName majorVersion + android.defaultConfig.versionCode + "-dev"
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel       : "Wire Dev",
                                    allowBackup            : "true",
                                    applicationIcon        : "@drawable/ic_launcher_wire_dev",
                                    sharedUserId           : "",
                                    use_audio_link         : "false",
                                    internal_features      : "true",
                                    localyticsAppKey       : getApiKey("localyticsAppKey"),
                                    hockeyAppKey           : getApiKey("hockeyAppKey")]

            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_HOCKEY_UPDATE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_EDGE_BACKEND', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_STAGING_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_GRIDOVERLAY', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEVELOPER_OPTIONS', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_LOADTIME_LOGGER_ENABLED', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_TEST_COUNTRY_CODE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_MENTIONING', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_TEST_GALLERY_ALLOWED', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_BACKEND_PICKER', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_UI', logLevelWarn()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_SE', logLevelSupress()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_AVS', logLevelVerbose()

            patchKeepSpecs()
        }

        candidate {
            applicationId "com.wire.candidate"
            versionName majorVersion + android.defaultConfig.versionCode + "-candidate"
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel       : "Wire Candidate",
                                    allowBackup            : "true",
                                    applicationIcon        : "@drawable/ic_launcher_wire_candidate",
                                    sharedUserId           : "",
                                    use_audio_link         : "false",
                                    internal_features      : "false",
                                    localyticsAppKey       : getApiKey("localyticsAppKey"),
                                    hockeyAppKey           : getApiKey("hockeyAppKeyCand")]

            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_HOCKEY_UPDATE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_EDGE_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_STAGING_BACKEND', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_GRIDOVERLAY', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEVELOPER_OPTIONS', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_LOADTIME_LOGGER_ENABLED', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_TEST_COUNTRY_CODE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_MENTIONING', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_ADDRESS_BOOK_INVITATIONS', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_TEST_GALLERY_ALLOWED', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_BACKEND_PICKER', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_UI', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_SE', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_AVS', logLevelVerbose()
        }

        prod {
            applicationId "com.wire"
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel       : "@string/app_name",
                                    allowBackup            : "false",
                                    applicationIcon        : "@drawable/ic_launcher_wire",
                                    sharedUserId           : "com.waz.userid",
                                    internal_features      : "false",
                                    use_audio_link         : "false",
                                    localyticsAppKey       : getApiKey("localyticsAppKeyProd"),
                                    hockeyAppKey           : getApiKey("hockeyAppKeyProd")]

            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_HOCKEY_UPDATE', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_EDGE_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_STAGING_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_GRIDOVERLAY', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEVELOPER_OPTIONS', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_LOADTIME_LOGGER_ENABLED', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_TEST_COUNTRY_CODE', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_MENTIONING', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_TEST_GALLERY_ALLOWED', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_BACKEND_PICKER', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_UI', logLevelSupress()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_SE', logLevelSupress()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_AVS', logLevelSupress()
        }

        internal {
            applicationId "com.wire.internal"
            versionName majorVersion + android.defaultConfig.versionCode + "-internal"
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules-test.txt'
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel : "Wire Internal",
                                    allowBackup      : "true",
                                    applicationIcon  : "@drawable/ic_launcher_wire_internal",
                                    sharedUserId     : "",
                                    use_audio_link   : "false",
                                    gcm_enabled      : "false",
                                    internal_features: "true",
                                    localyticsAppKey : getApiKey("localyticsAppKey"),
                                    hockeyAppKey     : getApiKey("hockeyAppKeyInternal")]

            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_HOCKEY_UPDATE', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_EDGE_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_STAGING_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_GRIDOVERLAY', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEVELOPER_OPTIONS', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_LOADTIME_LOGGER_ENABLED', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_TEST_COUNTRY_CODE', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_MENTIONING', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_ADDRESS_BOOK_INVITATIONS', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_TEST_GALLERY_ALLOWED', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_BACKEND_PICKER', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_UI', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_SE', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_AVS', logLevelVerbose()
        }

        avs {
            applicationId "com.wire.avs"
            versionName majorVersion + android.defaultConfig.versionCode + "-avs"
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules-test.txt'
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel       : "Wire AVS",
                                    allowBackup            : "true",
                                    applicationIcon        : "@drawable/ic_launcher_wire_playground",
                                    sharedUserId           : "",
                                    use_audio_link         : "false",
                                    internal_features      : "true",
                                    localyticsAppKey       : getApiKey("localyticsAppKey"),
                                    hockeyAppKey           : getApiKey("hockeyAppKeyAvs")]

            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_HOCKEY_UPDATE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_EDGE_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_STAGING_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_GRIDOVERLAY', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEVELOPER_OPTIONS', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_LOADTIME_LOGGER_ENABLED', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_TEST_COUNTRY_CODE', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_MENTIONING', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_TEST_GALLERY_ALLOWED', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_BACKEND_PICKER', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_UI', logLevelSupress()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_SE', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_AVS', logLevelVerbose()
        }

        qaavs {
            applicationId "com.wire.qaavs"
            versionName majorVersion + android.defaultConfig.versionCode + "-qaavs"
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules-test.txt'
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel       : "Wire QA AVS",
                                    allowBackup            : "true",
                                    applicationIcon        : "@drawable/ic_launcher_wire_playground",
                                    sharedUserId           : "",
                                    use_audio_link         : "false",
                                    internal_features      : "true",
                                    localyticsAppKey       : getApiKey("localyticsAppKey"),
                                    hockeyAppKey           : getApiKey("hockeyAppKeyQaavs")]

            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_HOCKEY_UPDATE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_EDGE_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_STAGING_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_GRIDOVERLAY', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEVELOPER_OPTIONS', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_LOADTIME_LOGGER_ENABLED', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_TEST_COUNTRY_CODE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_MENTIONING', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_ADDRESS_BOOK_INVITATIONS', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_TEST_GALLERY_ALLOWED', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_BACKEND_PICKER', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_UI', logLevelSupress()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_SE', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_AVS', logLevelVerbose()
        }

        experimental {
            applicationId "com.wire.x"
            versionName majorVersion + android.defaultConfig.versionCode + "-exp"
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules-test.txt'
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel       : "Wire Exp",
                                    allowBackup            : "true",
                                    applicationIcon        : "@drawable/ic_launcher_wire_playground",
                                    sharedUserId           : "",
                                    use_audio_link         : "false",
                                    internal_features      : "true",
                                    localyticsAppKey       : getApiKey("localyticsAppKey"),
                                    hockeyAppKey           : getApiKey("hockeyAppKeyExperimental")]

            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_HOCKEY_UPDATE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_EDGE_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_STAGING_BACKEND', 'false'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_GRIDOVERLAY', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEVELOPER_OPTIONS', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_LOADTIME_LOGGER_ENABLED', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_TEST_COUNTRY_CODE', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_MENTIONING', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_TEST_GALLERY_ALLOWED', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_BACKEND_PICKER', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_UI', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_SE', logLevelVerbose()
            buildConfigField 'int', 'LOG_LEVEL_AVS', logLevelVerbose()

            patchKeepSpecs()
        }
    }


    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs += ['build/generated/source/apt/androidTest/dev/debug']
        }

        test {
            scala.srcDirs += ['src/test/scala']
        }
    }

    /* to ignore error where multiple libs have this file */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'APK_LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

def patchKeepSpecs() {
    def taskClass = "com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.multidex.CreateManifestKeepList";
    def clazz = this.class.classLoader.loadClass(taskClass)
    def keepSpecsField = clazz.getDeclaredField("KEEP_SPECS")
    keepSpecsField.setAccessible(true)
    def keepSpecsMap = (Map) keepSpecsField.get(null)
    if (keepSpecsMap.remove("activity") != null) {
        println "KEEP_SPECS patched: removed 'activity' root"
    } else {
        println "Failed to patch KEEP_SPECS: no 'activity' root found"
    }

    if (keepSpecsMap.remove("instrumentation") != null) {
        println "KEEP_SPECS patched: removed 'instrumentation' root"
    } else {
        println "Failed to patch KEEP_SPECS: no 'instrumentation' root found"
    }

    if (keepSpecsMap.remove("service") != null) {
        println "KEEP_SPECS patched: removed 'service' root"
    } else {
        println "Failed to patch KEEP_SPECS: no 'service' root found"
    }


}

afterEvaluate {
    //Pretty big hack to keep the main dex class list down
    Task collectTask = project.tasks.findByName("collectDevDebugMultiDexComponents")
    Task processManifestTask = project.tasks.findByName("processDevDebugManifest")

    if (!collectTask || !processManifestTask)
        return

    collectTask.dependsOn(processManifestTask) << {
        File androidManifestFile = processManifestTask.outputs.files.filter {
            it.absolutePath.matches('.*full.*AndroidManifest\\.xml')
        }.singleFile

        File manifestKeepFile = collectTask.outputs.files.filter {
            it.absolutePath.endsWith('manifest_keep.txt')
        }.singleFile

        def nonExportedClasses = new XmlSlurper().parse(androidManifestFile).application.'**'.findAll { node ->
            if (node.name().matches('(activity|service|receiver|provider)')) {
                return (node.'@android:exported' == 'false'
                        || (node.'@android:exported' != 'true'
                        && node.'intent-filter'.size() == 0))
            }
        }.collect {
            it.'@android:name'.text()
        }

        def manifestKeepText = manifestKeepFile.text
        manifestKeepFile.withWriter('utf-8') { writer ->
            manifestKeepText.eachLine { line ->
                boolean isNonExportedLine = nonExportedClasses.any {
                    line.contains(it)
                }

                if (!isNonExportedLine)
                    writer.writeLine(line)
            }
        }
    }
}

dexinfo {
    maxDepth 2
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':wire-core')
    compile project(':wire-ui')
    compile project(':lintlib')

//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile deps.scala
    compile deps.multidex
    compile deps.supportv4
    compile deps.supportv13
    compile deps.supportdesign
    compile deps.appcompatv7
    compile deps.supportannotations
    compile deps.recyclerview
    compile deps.threetenabp
    compile deps.hockey
    compile deps.audioNotifications
    compile deps.localytics
    compile deps.roundedimageview
    compile deps.rebound

    // For spotify
    compile deps.spotifyAuth

    // For Video Message preview
    compile deps.mp4parser

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    compile deps.psBase
    compile deps.psGcm
    compile deps.psMaps
    compile deps.psLocation
    compile deps.cardview

    //Used for animating incoming messages
    compile deps.nineoldandroids
    // For using local files in app/libs
    //compile (name:'avs', ext:'aar')
    //compile (name:'audio-notifications', ext:'aar')
    //compile (name:'zmessaging-android', ext:'aar')

    // Test dependencies
    testCompile deps.junit
    testCompile(deps.testutils) {
        exclude module: 'aspectjrt'
        exclude module: 'isoparser'
        exclude module: 'zmessaging-android'
    }
    testCompile(deps.scalatest) {
        exclude module: 'scala-library'
    }
    testCompile deps.espressoIntents
    testCompile deps.hamcrestCore
    testCompile deps.hamcrestLib
    testCompile deps.hamcrestIntegration
    testCompile deps.mockitoCore
    testCompile deps.espresso
    testCompile deps.supportannotations

    //AndroidTest dependencies
    //androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile deps.junit
    androidTestCompile deps.espressoIntents
    androidTestCompile deps.testRunner
    androidTestCompile deps.testRules
    androidTestCompile deps.espresso
    androidTestCompile deps.supportannotations
    androidTestCompile deps.mockitoCore
    androidTestCompile deps.dexmaker
    androidTestCompile deps.dexmakerDx
    androidTestCompile deps.dexmakerMockito

    //Translations
    compile deps.translations
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-feature", "-target:jvm-1.7", "-Xfuture", "-deprecation", "-Yinline-warnings", "-Ywarn-unused-import", "-encoding", "UTF-8"]
}

def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('MM/dd HH:mm:ss')
    return formattedDate
}

def getApiKey(String property) {
    if (file("$projectDir/api-keys.properties").exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("$projectDir/api-keys.properties"))
        return properties.getProperty(property)
    } else if (property.startsWith("localytics")) {
        return "00000000000000000000000-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    } else {
        return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "")
    }
}

// Same values as in log_levels.xml
// (workaround for R not being available in BuildConfig for test flavor)
def logLevelVerbose() { return '2' }

def logLevelDebug() { return '3' }

def logLevelInfo() { return '4' }

def logLevelWarn() { return '5' }

def logLevelError() { return '6' }

def logLevelSupress() { return '99' }
```

**Build.gradle(Module:wire-core):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply from: "${project.rootDir}/app/config/quality.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize '4g'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile deps.appcompatv7
    compile deps.timber

    // TODO  Nasty hack to be able to build add only one wire-core flavor to the build
    // TODO  (I know, it sucks, will think of a better way to do this, and we need this
    // TODO   when there are different SE APIs in dev vs internal/prod)
    boolean dev = true;
    boolean internal = false;
    boolean prod = false;
    for (String taskName : gradle.startParameter.taskNames) {
        if (taskName.contains("Dev")) {
            dev = true;
            break;
        }
        if (taskName.contains("Internal") || taskName.contains("Experimental") || taskName.contains("Qaavs") || taskName.contains("Avs")) {
            internal = true;
            dev = false;
            break;
        }
        if (taskName.contains("Prod") || taskName.contains("Candidate")) {
            prod = true;
            dev = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    def avs_artifact = "$avsGroup:$avsName";
    def avs_version = avsInternalVersion;
    def se_version = zMessagingReleaseVersion;

    if (dev) {
        avs_version = avsInternalVersion;
        se_version = zMessagingDevVersion;
    }

    if (internal) {
        avs_version = avsInternalVersion;
        se_version = zMessagingDevVersion;
    }

    if (prod) {
        avs_version = avsVersion;
    }

    compile "$avs_artifact:$avs_version"
    compile("com.wire:zmessaging-android:$se_version") {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle(Module:wire-ui):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: "${project.rootDir}/app/config/quality.gradle"
apply plugin: 'hugo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize '4g'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile deps.appcompatv7
    compile(deps.supportpreferences) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile deps.supportannotations
    compile deps.roundedimageview
    compile deps.timber
    compile deps.recyclerview
    compile project(':wire-core')
    compile deps.threetenabp
    compile deps.supportdesign
    compile deps.preferences
    compile(deps.supportpreferences) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile deps.rebound

    androidTestCompile deps.testRunner
    androidTestCompile deps.testRules
    androidTestCompile deps.espresso
}
```

Comment: Start with running build from command line with `-s` (to print error stacktrace) and `-i` (to print INFO log output) and investigate the output.

Comment: Please add more of the gradle output to your post. For reference, please see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately None of answers Work, In my Case, going to 
view ---> tool windows --->Build variants 
and then changing the Build Variant of App from AvsDebug to DevDebug Solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen for these reasons

1. If you have a large set of libraries included in your project.
2. If the libraries you included are not compatible with each other or with the app (like in app if you included *android support-v4.jar* and one of library using *android design-support* librares.
3. You may already hit 65k methods in your App.
4. Sometimes this happens if the device you are running the app has not enough RAM, so consider closing some apps.

### If your problem is either 1 or 3

along with `multiDexEnabled true`
adding `dexOptions` inside `android` block helped me

```
dexOptions {
preDexLibraries = false
incremental true
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

and If you are Running unit test add `MultiDex.install(this);` inside your  *`Application`* class's `onCreate()` method

1. Restart Android studio.
2. Clean the Project.
3. Build it again.

#### If option 2 is your problem then you have to remove that library, Clean the project and Build again

Comment: have you added `android:largeHeap="true"` inside your application tag?

Comment: i added the gradle files to question

Answer (score 1):

**You need to follow these steps**

**As you already do**

```
  defaultConfig {
  ...
  ...
   multiDexEnabled true
}
```

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

In Your **AndroidManifest.xml** add this lines **android:name**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
```

And In your **build.gradle** also add

```
dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

if you are using some thing like this

```
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

Than you used like this for each one Try exclude module to support version

```
 compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0') {
 exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
```

And Also if you compile the jar file with compile like this

```
  compile files('libs/yourjar.jar')
```

Than remove this or comment

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: this didnt solve my problem, i included the gradle files in question...