# Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android

pleas solve this problem. ?

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzk;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: share you app build.gradle file

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try to add this on build.gradle (app module).

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```

I hope it will work as per your code snippets.

Comment: this is not the only step required actually

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko what other steps are required?