# When I want to run my app, then I get Execution Failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My Android Studio is version 1.5.1
Can someone help me?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Try clean and build project.

Comment: I've tried clean and build project, but nothing happen. @Shashanth

Comment: Check this similiar StackOverflow [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf?rq=1) and one more thing update your Android Studio to latest version 2.2.2

Comment: What is the exact stack trace above this message?