# How to use YouTube Analytics API in Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I need to get some statistics about a certain youtube channel searched by user, and YouTube Data API doesn't provide me enough data. So how can I use YouTube Analytics API to get more data abou an youtube channel?
I can't use their lib:

`compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtubeAnalytics:v1-rev73-1.22.0'`

because it gives me error, and I don't want to enable multidex:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

all my dependences are:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.+'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1"
compile ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtubeAnalytics:v1-rev73-1.22.0'){
        exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/#supported-reports) for the different types of reports you can retrieve using the API. Most of the workarounds I have read is to add `multiDexEnabled true` to your app `build.gradle` file.

- [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)
- [Android Studio TransformException : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf)

Since you don't want to enable it, I can suggest to [remove unused code with ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html). You should [enable code shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) to run ProGuard for your release builds. Enabling shrinking ensures you are not shipping unused code with your APKs.

You can refer with this [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35377317/5832311) on how to get both statistics and snippet printed to the console with single api call.